# How to remove gradient layer in swift

Tags: swift3, cagradientlayer

```
Code:

    extension CAGradientLayer
    {
        func changeStatusBarColor() -> CAGradientLayer
        {
            var height = 20
            let Size = UIScreen.main.bounds

            let darkViolet = UIColor(hexString: "#44377D")
            let lightViolet = UIColor(hexString: "##686CCD")

            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:Int(Size.width), height: height)
            gradientLayer.colors =  [darkViolet,lightViolet ].map{$0.cgColor}
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
            return gradientLayer
        }
    }

     let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.name = "masklayer"
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer.changeStatusBarColor())

            for layer in self.view.layer.sublayers! {
                print("layer name:", layer.name)
                if layer.name == "masklayer" {
                    layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
            }
```

I applied gradient colour for status bar.when I tried to remove sublayer  with above code it does not remove sublayer.what is wrong with my code.any help will be appreicated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
extension CAGradientLayer
{
    func changeStatusBarColor() -> CAGradientLayer
    {
        var height = 20
        let Size = UIScreen.main.bounds

        let darkViolet = UIColor(hexString: "#44377D")
        let lightViolet = UIColor(hexString: "##686CCD")

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:Int(Size.width), height: height)
        gradientLayer.colors =  [darkViolet,lightViolet ].map{$0.cgColor}
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

        gradientLayer.name = self.name

        return gradientLayer
    }
}
```

add the **gradientLayer.name = self.name** in your changeStatusBarColor() function.